# i am receiving this error when i am executing shell script - bash: ./helloworld.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

I am executing the program below in Ubuntu and getting an error - `bash: ./helloworld.sh: No such file or directory`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

I checked bash and also gave `chmod` permissions

Comment: You're trying to run the script in the wrong directory or the filename is different.
You'd get a different error message if it was a permission issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things I would check:

- Confirm `/bin/bash` exists and is executable
- Confirm `./helloworld.sh` exists
- Confirm `./helloworld.sh` is executable

Comment: Hi Shane, you mean to check them by using ls -lrt  or anyother way

Comment: @VijayShankar You could use `ls -l ./helloworld.sh` and `ls -l /bin/bash` to verify that those two files exist.

Comment: @kusalnanda, please find below scrennshot and guide

Comment: @VijayShankar If you wish to update your question with further information, then do so by editing the question.